# Automatically Add Diacritic/Accent Marks to a Non-English Document

Tags: python, machine-learning, automation, nlp, artificial-intelligence

In my spare time, I am transcribing a very old, rare book written in Romanian (in fact, it is the only remaining copy, to my knowledge). It was written over a hundred years ago, well before any computers existed. As such, no digital copies exist, and I am manually transcribing and digitizing it.

The book is thousands of pages long, and it is surprisingly time consuming (for me, at least) to add diacritic and accented marks (`ă/â/î/ş/ţ`) to every single word as I type. If I omit the marks and just type the bare letters (i.e `a` instead of `ă/â`), I am able to type more than twice as fast, which is a huge benefit. Currently I am typing everything directly into a `.tex` file to apply special formatting for the pages and illustrations.

However, I know that eventually I will have to add all these marks back into the text, and it seems tedious/unecessary to do all that manually, since I already have all the letters. I'm looking for some way to automatically/semi-automatically **ADD** diacritic/accent marks to a large body of text (*not* remove - I see plenty of questions asking how to remove the marks on SO).

I tried searching for large corpora of Romanian words ([this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ManiacDC/TypingAid/master/Wordlists/Wordlist%20Romanian.txt) and [this](https://github.com/dumitrescustefan/RoWordNet) were the most promising two), but everything I found fell short, missing at least a few words on any random sample of text I fed it (I used a short python script). It doesn't help that the book uses many archaic/uncommon words or uncommon spellings of words.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might go about this? There are no dumb ideas here - any document format, machine learning technique, coding language, professional tool, etc that you can think of that might help is appreciated.

I should also note that I have substantial coding experience, and would not consider it a waste of time to build something myself. Tbh, I think it might be beneficial to the community, since I could not find such a tool in **any** western language (french, czech, serbian, etc). Just need some guidance on how to get started.

Comment: Have you considered some type of OCR as the first step, trained on a Romanian corpus (or several) that at least have all the correct diacritical marks? Even if it's only a 50% success rate, that cuts your work in half.

Comment: @MattDMo - My first thought was OCR as well, but the book is sort of falling apart and some of the words are quite faded, which I imagine would make it difficult. The other problem is I can't find reliable romanian corpora - some are better than others, but still missing a lot.

Comment: I don't speak Romanian, but in most languages which use diacritics, they are significant because there are also words with different meanings which lack them. Different orthographies have different amounts of overlap, and some are more systematically marking up phonetic values even when there is no way that an unaccented version of a character could occur in the same position; but my vague prediction would be that you'll need some amount of manual review even if you find a tool which can propose diacritics for words which lack them.

Comment: Perhaps a more fruitful approach would be to improve your input environment so that you can input correct diacritics more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71831818) is a static approach which will work depending on how good the word-list is.
So if a word is missing from this list it will never handled.

Moreover, as in many other languages, there are cases where two (or more) words exists with the same characters but different diacritics.
For Romanian I found the following example: peste = over vs. pesţe = fish.
These cases cannot be handled in a straightforward way either.
This is especially an issue, if the text you're converted contains words which aren't used anymore in today's language, especially diacritised ones.

In this answer I will present an alternative using machine learning.
The only caveat to this is that I couldn't find a publicly available trained model doing diacritic restoration for Romanian.
You may find some luck in contacting the authors of the papers I will mention here to see if they'd be willing to send their trained models for you to use.
Otherwise, you'll have to train yourself, which I'll give some pointers on.
I will try to give a comprehensive overview to get you started, but further reading is encouraged.

Although this process may be laborious, it can give you [99% accuracy](https://aclanthology.org/2020.coling-main.581/) with the right tools.

### Language Model

The language model is a model which can be thought of as having a high-level "understanding" of the language.
It's typically pre-trained on raw text corpora.
Although you can train your own, be wary that these models are quite [expensive to pre-train](https://aclanthology.org/P19-1355/).

Whilst [multilingual models](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/multilingual.md) can be used, language-specific models typically fare better if trained with enough data.
Luckily, there are publicly language models available for Romanian, such as [RoBERT](https://aclanthology.org/2020.coling-main.581/).
This language model is based on [BERT](https://aclanthology.org/N19-1423/), an architecture used extensively in Natural Language Processing & is more or less the standard in the field due as it attained state-of-the-art results in English & other languages.

In fact there are three variants: [base](https://huggingface.co/readerbench/RoBERT-base), [large](https://huggingface.co/readerbench/RoBERT-large), & [small](https://huggingface.co/readerbench/RoBERT-small).
The larger the model, the better the results, due to the larger representation power.
But larger models will also have a higher footprint in terms of memory.

Loading these models is very easy with the [transformers](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/index) library.
For instance, the [base model](https://huggingface.co/readerbench/RoBERT-base):

```py
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("readerbench/RoBERT-base")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("readerbench/RoBERT-base")
inputs = tokenizer("exemplu de propoziție", return_tensors="pt")
outputs = model(**inputs)
```

The `outputs` above will contain vector representations of the inputted texts, more commonly know as "word embeddings".
Language models are then **fine-tuned** to a downstream task — in your case, diacritic restoration — and would take these embeddings as input.

### Fine-tuning

I couldn't find any publicly available fine-tuned models, so you'll have to fine-tune your own unless you find a model yourself.

To fine-tune a language model, we need to build a task-specific architecture which will be trained on some dataset.
The dataset is used to tell the model how the input is & how we'd like the output to be.

#### Dataset

From [Diacritics Restoration using BERT with Analysis on Czech language](https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/pbml/116/art-naplava-straka-strakova.pdf), there's a [publicly available dataset](https://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/repository/xmlui/handle/11234/1-2607) for a number of languages including Romanian.
The dataset annotations will also depend on which fine-tuning architecture you use (more on that below).

In general, you'd choose a dataset which you trust has a high-quality of of diacritics.
From this text you can then build annotations automatically by producing the undiacritised variants of the words as well as the corresponding labels.

Keep in mind that this or any other dataset you'll use will contain biases especially in terms of the domain the annotated texts originate from.
Depending on how much data you have already transcribed, you may also want to build a dataset using your texts.

#### Architecture

The architecture you choose will have a bearing on the downstream performance you use & the amount of custom code you'll have to do.

##### Word-level

The aforementioned work, [Diacritics Restoration using BERT with Analysis on Czech language](https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/pbml/116/art-naplava-straka-strakova.pdf), use a token-level classification mechanism where each word is is labelled with a set of instructions of the type of diacritic marks to insert at which character index.
For example, the undiacritised word "dite" with instruction set `1:CARON;3:ACUTE` indicates adding the appropriate diacritic marks at index 1 and index 3 to result in "dítě".

Since this is a token-level classification task, there's not much custom code you have to do, as you can directly use a [`BertForTokenClassification`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertForTokenClassification).
Refer to the [authors' code](https://github.com/ufal/bert-diacritics-restoration/blob/master/run_diacritization.py) for a more complete example.

One sidenote is that the authors use a multililingual language model.
This can be easily replaced with another language model such as [RoBERT](https://aclanthology.org/2020.coling-main.581/) mentioned above.

##### Character-level

Alternatively, [the RoBERT paper](https://aclanthology.org/2020.coling-main.581/) use a character-level model.
From the paper, each character is annotated as one of the following:

> make no modification to the current character (e.g., a → a), add circumflex mark (e.g., a → â and i → î), add breve mark (e.g., a →  ̆ă), and two more classes for adding comma below (e.g., s → ş and t → ţ)

Here you will have to build your own custom model (instead of the `BertForTokenClassification` above).
But, the rest of the training code will largely be the same.
Here's a template for the model `class` which can be used using the [transformers](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/index) library:

```py
from transformers import BertModel, BertPreTrainedModel

class BertForDiacriticRestoration(BertPreTrainedModel):

    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.bert = BertModel(config)
        ...

    def forward(
        self,
        input_ids=None,
        attention_mask=None,
        token_type_ids=None
    ):
        ...
```

### Evaluation

In each section there's plethora of options for you to choose from.
A bit of pragmatic advice I'll offer is to start simple & complicate things if you want to improve things further.
Keep a testing set to measure if the changes you're making result in improvements or degradation over your previous setup.

Crucially, I'd suggest that at least a small part of your testing set is texts coming from the texts you have transcribed yourself, the more you use the better.
Primarily, this is data you annotated yourself, so you are more sure of the quality of this data then any other publicly available source.
Secondly, when you are testing on data coming from the target domain, you stand a better chance of more accurately evaluating your systems more accurately to your target task, due to certain biases which might be present from other domains.

Comment: I agree, Bob’s approach, while valid, is inherently limited by the quality of the corpus itself, which I’ve proven through my own short tests to be lacking. I anticipated that machine learning would be the way to go. I’ve heard of BERT before, but never RoBERT - that sounds really promising. I will look into this more deeply this week and let you know how I make out. And Dw if the bounty expires or anything - this project is very important to me, so whoever’s answer gets me the closest will get a bounty, I’ll make sure of it.

Comment: Another point to note is that a language model can be further pre-trained to adapt it to a particular domain, see for example [Don't Stop Pretraining](https://aclanthology.org/2020.acl-main.740/). From what I could gather, the book seems to be quite old, so your text may very well have certain differences in the text distribution compared to the corpora used to pre-train RoBERT (which are pre-dominantly web-based). Whilst pre-training from scratch may be unfeasible it might make sense to pre-train RoBERT further for a few epochs on some of texts you've transcribed.

Comment: I was thinking something similar - before I got tired of adding diacritics due to how long it took to type on an American keyboard, I actually managed to write out a few chapters with all the appropriate diacritics, so I'm thinking I'll feed those in as training data (perhaps with a higher weight than the rest of the training set?) to pretrain the model for my specific use case.

Comment: @v0rtex20k, if you're thinking of pre-training further an existing model there's no need to assign a higher weight since you'll only be feeding in your corpus & won't rerun the initial generic Romanian pre-training done be RoBERT, but rather using the RoBERT model as initial weights. You can rerun pre-training from scratch with a mixture of corpora & have your texts have a higher learning rate for instance, but I'd suggest to start simple & complicate things only if you need to (especially considering that pre-training from scratch can be quite costly).

Comment: After reading the article on memory consumption, I see what you mean by expensive - looks like rerunning pre-training from scratch may be a bit too challenging. I will stick with the pre-trained model and just feed my data to it.

Answer (score 2):

What comes to my mind is a simple replacement. About 10% of the words could are differentiated only by the diacritics, e.g. `abandona` and `abandonă`, those will not be fixed. But the other 90% will be fixed.

```js
const dictUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ManiacDC/TypingAid/master/Wordlists/Wordlist%20Romanian.txt';
async function init(){
  console.log('init')
  const response = await fetch(dictUrl);
  const text = await response.text();
  console.log(`${text.length} characters`)
  const words = text.split(/\s+/mg);
  console.log(`${words.length} words`)
  const denormalize = {}
  let unique_count = 0;
  for(const w of words){
    const nw = w.normalize('NFD').replace(/[^a-z]/ig, '')
    if(!Object.hasOwnProperty.call(denormalize, nw)){
      denormalize[nw] = [];
      unique_count += 1;
    }
    denormalize[nw].push(w);
  }
  console.log(`${unique_count} unique normalized words`)
  
  for(const el of document.querySelectorAll('textarea')){
    handleSpellings(el, denormalize);
  }
}

function handleSpellings(el, dict){
    el.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
      if(e.key == ' ')
      setTimeout(function () {
         const restored = el.value.replace(
           /\b\S+(?=[\x20-\x7f])/g, 
            (s) => {
              const s2 = dict[s] ? dict[s][0] : s;
              console.log([s, dict[s], s2]);
              return s2;
            }
         );
         el.value = restored;
      }, 0)
    })
}

window.addEventListener('load', init);
```

```html
<body>

<textarea width=40 height=10 style="width: 40em; height:10em;">

</textarea>
</body>
```